# Can't able to resolve dependencies of the SqsService when i tried to use it in Custom Provider

Tags: javascript, nestjs, amazon-sqs

I'm aiming to make the code less dependent on specific parts. My idea is to create a provider, which would allow me to easily switch between using a queueService or bypassing the queue during local development. Additionally, using this provider would make it simpler in the future if we decide to switch to cloud tasks. I'd only need to change the class, and the provider will handle the rest.

```
import { SqsService } from '@ssut/nestjs-sqs';
import { SqsOptions } from '@ssut/nestjs-sqs/dist/sqs.types';
import { DiscoveryService } from '@golevelup/nestjs-discovery';
import { SQS_OPTIONS } from '@ssut/nestjs-sqs/dist/sqs.constants';


export interface QueueResolver {
  send(queue: string, message: any): Promise;
}

export const QueueProvider = {
  provide: 'QueueResolver',
  useFactory: (options: SqsOptions, discover: DiscoveryService) => new SqsService(options,discover),
  inject: [SQS_OPTIONS, DiscoveryService]
}
```

Here is core.module.ts

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailProvider } from 'core/mail/mail.provider';
import * as path from 'path';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PugAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/pug.adapter';
import { QueueProvider } from './queue/queue.resolver';  

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: {
          host: configService.get('MAIL').host,
          secure: false,
          port: configService.get('MAIL').port,
          auth: {
            user: configService.get('MAIL').auth.user,
            pass: configService.get('MAIL').auth.pass,
          },
        },
        defaults: {
          from: `"${configService.get('MAIL').from.name}" <${configService.get('MAIL').from.email}>`,
        },
        template: {
          dir: path.join(__dirname, './mail/templates'),
          adapter: new PugAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    MailProvider,
    QueueProvider
  ],
  exports: [MailProvider],
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

`\[ExceptionHandler\] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SqsService (?, DiscoveryService). Please make sure that the argument Symbol(SQS_OPTIONS) at index \[0\] is available in the CoreModule context.`

I'm seeking guidance on how to properly inject or provide dependencies, especially related to the SQS_OPTIONS argument.

Comment: Can you show the `CoreModule` and the `SqsService`?

Comment: Here's `SqsService` https://github.com/ssut/nestjs-sqs/blob/master/lib/sqs.service.ts and its module https://github.com/ssut/nestjs-sqs/blob/master/lib/sqs.module.ts. in my `CoreModule` i've  simply imported `QueueProvider`

Comment: Again, can you show your `CoreModule`. That's important to understand why this error is the way it is

Comment: "Sure, here's the `CoreModule`